# How to define nested array in Mongoose Schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to define the Model schema below:

```
var myLoc = Schema({
extent : {
    type: String,
    coordinates: 
        [   
            [
                [Number, Number],
                [Number, Number],
                [Number, Number],
                [Number, Number],
                [Number, Number]
            ] 
        ]
    }
}, {collection: 'myLoc'});
```

[image]

Below code only printed _id field, however if I remove the extent in my schema above it will printed the field.

```
myLoc.find({})
    .exec(function (err, result) {
    console.log(result); <----- only print _id,
    console.log(result.extent.coordinates);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a mongoose schema as follows

```
const MyLocationSchema = new Schema({
    extent: {
        type: {
            type: String,
        },
        coOrdinates: [[[Number]]]
    }
});

module.exports = MyLocation = mongoose.model('MyLocation', MyLocationSchema);
```

Here, I am adding a stored document from the db collection which is created via the above schema,

```
> db.mylocations.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c10de4fb5f14ec21b3fa24b"),
    "extent" : {
        "coOrdinates" : [
            [
                [
                    1,
                    2
                ],
                [
                    1,
                    2
                ],
                [
                    1,
                    2
                ],
                [
                    1,
                    2
                ],
                [
                    1,
                    2
                ]
            ]
        ],
        "type" : "poly"
    },
    "__v" : 0
}
```